# Selecting item with Max count in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a voting table it have fields `id,itemId,votes,voteDate`.Vot field have values either 1(up vote)or-1(down vote).
i wants to select the itemId which have maximum up vote and maximum down vote (i mean if my item 1 have 3 upvotes  and my item 2 have 5 upvotes i want to get select item 2)in a specific time period(1 week).
my code is

```
DB::table('votes')
->leftjoin('items','items.id','=','votes.itemId')
->select('items.title','items.image',DB::raw('sum(votes.votes) as voteSum'))
->whereBetween('voteDate',array($timePeriod,$today))
->get();
```

I know this query is wrong.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First you should find `$sum_max_vote_in_the_date_interval`.
Then use this

```
DB::table('votes')
->leftjoin('items','items.id','=','votes.itemId')
->select('items.title','items.image',DB::raw('sum(votes.votes) as voteSum'))
->whereBetween('voteDate',array($timePeriod,$today))
->havingRaw("SUM(`votes`.`votes`) = ".$sum_max_vote_in_the_date_interval)
->group_by(`votes`.'id')
->get();
```

**OR**

```
DB::table('votes')
->leftjoin('items','items.id','=','votes.itemId')
->select('items.title','items.image',DB::raw('sum(votes.votes) as voteSum'))
->whereBetween('voteDate',array($timePeriod,$today))
->havingRaw("SUM(`votes`.`votes`) = `votes`.`votes`")
->group_by(`votes`.'id')
->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here Each item have Vote 1 or -1.So Max function do not gives me required result.
And What is $max_vote_in_the_date_interval.Where can i write it in my query.?

Comment: Undefined variable: sum_max_vote_in_the_date_interval
getting error.

Comment: first you have to find the `$sum_max_vote_in_the_date_interval`(5 in the case u mentioned)

Comment: i am not sure about the OR part.. Please try and see... Waiting for update

Comment: I tried both but do not works.
And is it need to use ';' in ->havingRaw("SUM(`votes`.`votes`) = ".$sum_max_vote_in_the_date_interval);
i removed that otherwise getting errors.
Anyway Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to use havingRow since you need to check aggregate functions `SUM`

Comment: Yes I'm trying on that function.

Comment: What is the error getting while executing `OR` part

Comment: unknown column votes.I don't know why i'm getting that error.Actually the column name is correct.

Comment: Trry changing `->havingRaw("SUM(`votes`.`votes`) = `votes`.`votes`")` ->
to `->havingRaw("SUM(`votes`.`votes`) > 4")`